# celery apply_async method report an error:Exception information must be have exception type

Tags: celery

the task definitation is here:

```
@ops_scheduler.task(bind=True, trail=True, default_retry_delay=1 * 60,
                    autoretry_for=(ScriptPreparationException, TaskExecuteCeleryException))
def script_exec_python_entry(self, script_content=None, script_params=None, deploy_config=None, local_config=None):
    self.update_state(state='STARTED', meta={'message': "任务已经开始执行,但尚未完成"})
    logger.info(f"任务开始执行，启动时间: {datetime.datetime.now()}")
    logger.info(f"环境信息: {self.request}")
    logger.info(
        f"任务参数: script_content={script_content}, script_params={script_params}, deploy_config={deploy_config}, local_config={local_config}")
    logger.info(f"传入的参数: {self.request.args}")  # 在日志中输出传入的参数
    try:
        py_script_exec = PyScriptTransferExecuteEntry(script_content, script_params, deploy_config, local_config)
        if not py_script_exec.is_valid():
            self.update_state("FAILURE", meta={"message": f"脚本非法"})
            raise ValueError("任务脚本非法")
        script_exec_result = py_script_exec.execute()
        self.update_state("SUCCESS", meta={"message": f"任务成功"})
        logger.info(f"任务输出: {script_exec_result}")
        logger.info(f"返回状态码: SUCCESS")
        return script_exec_result
    except ScriptExecutionException as exc_e:
        self.update_state(state='FAILURE', meta={'message': "任务失败"})
        logger.error(f"返回状态码:FAILURE")
        logger.exception(f"任务失败:{exc_e}")
    except UnknownExecutionException as unknown_e:
        self.update_state(state='FAILURE', meta={'message': "任务失败"})
        logger.error(f"返回状态码: FAILURE")
        logger.exception(f"任务失败:{unknown_e}")
    except ValueError as run_e:
        self.update_state(state='FAILURE', meta={'message': "任务失败"})
        logger.error(f"返回状态码: FAILURE,")
        logger.exception(f"任务失败:{run_e}")
    except ScriptPreparationException as e:
        self.update_state("RETRY", meta={"message": "任务正在重试"})
        logger.error(f"返回状态码: RETRY")
        logger.exception("任务正在重试")
        raise e
    except Exception as e:
        self.update_state(state='FAILURE', meta={'message': "任务失败"})
        logger.error(f"返回状态码: FAILURE")
        logger.exception("任务失败")
        raise TaskExecuteCeleryException(str(e))
```

And the necessary definition information is as follows:

```
class ScriptPreparationException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return f"脚本执行前准备异常: {self.message}"

class TaskExecuteCeleryException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return f"任务执行celery层面异常: {self.message}"
```

when I try to call script_exec_python_entry.apply_async() # the specific paramments are not shown here.
the celery report an error:Exception information must be have exception type

Comment: Can we see an entire error message from Celery please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.